# Android Search Listview duplicating items from JSON using EditText

Tags: java, android, json

I'm creating a simple search activity using EditText, ListView, JSON and Database, Every time i enter text in EditText, the listview must update(I'm using mysql, Select query LIKE), where the ListView that contains Items from Database using JSON, the items must be updated from the given condition using LIKE method, but it keeps in duplicating item in ListView every time i enter text.

```
 inputSearch.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence cs, int arg1, int arg2, int arg3) {
            name = inputSearch.getText().toString();
            searcher(name);

        }

        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence arg0, int arg1, int arg2,
                                      int arg3) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        }
    });

  String result;

private void searcher(String searched){

    class searching extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String>{
        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... params) {

            String paramSearched = params[0];
            HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet("http://....p.com/searchD.php?name=" + paramSearched);
            try {
                HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpGet);
                InputStream is = httpResponse.getEntity().getContent();
                InputStreamReader inputStreamReader = new InputStreamReader(is);
                BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(inputStreamReader);
                StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
                String line = null;
                while ((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
                    stringBuilder.append(line + "\n");
                }
                result = stringBuilder.toString();
            }catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            try{

                JSONObject obj = new JSONObject(result);
                nameslist = obj.getJSONArray("list");
                for(int i = 0; i < nameslist.length(); i++){
                    JSONObject c = nameslist.getJSONObject(i);
                    String id = c.getString("ID");
                    String name = c.getString("Name");

                    HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
                    map.put("ID", id);
                    map.put("Name", name);

                    listofnames.add(map);
                }
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return null;
        }
        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
            pDialog = new ProgressDialog(Search.this);
            pDialog.setMessage("Searching Name. Please wait...");
            pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
            pDialog.setCancelable(false);
            pDialog.show();
        }
        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String s) {
            pDialog.dismiss();

            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(
                            Search.this, listofnames,
                            R.layout.list_item1, new String[]{"ID",
                            "Name"},
                            new int[]{R.id.pid, R.id.name});

                    lv.setAdapter(adapter);
                }
            });
            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

        }
    }
      searching sh  = new searching();
   sh.execute(searched);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you should clear the "listofnames" list before you add new data into it to keep the list data newest and not duplicated.